# Is there are way to get rowIDs of first occurrences of value from codechunks?

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to get that realized?
example:(distribution is random)

```
ID    size
1      x
2      x
3      x
4      x
5      x
0      2
0      x
0      x
0      x
4      x
5      x
0      4
0      x
0      x
0      x
4      x
5      x
0      3
0      x
0      x
0      x
4      x
5      x
```

This is just an example but very hard to code for me.
The x's are random numeric and not relevant. The values I need are the shown integers in the size column, so everytime a ID==0 occurrs, I need the first size value.

Comment: What sort of output do you need?

Comment: I do need the values of size in those rows since I have to iterate through the whole list and use them for other operations. I will also need any other column in that row. Also the Sum of a column in all the previous rows after the last 0 occurrance. I thought that would be to much to ask for so I went with the initial question to get a starting point. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data.table::lag()` to create a new column which lags one row behind `ID`. If `d` is your data.frame:

```
d <- d %>% dplyr::mutate(prevID = lag(ID))

   ID size prevID
1   1   44     NA
2   2   55      1
3   3   66      2
4   4   77      3
5   5   88      4
6   0    2      5
7   0   33      0
8   0   44      0
9   0   55      0
10  4   66      0
11  5   77      4
12  0    4      5
13  0   11      0
14  0   22      0
15  0   33      0
16  4   44      0
17  5   55      4
18  0    3      5
19  0   44      0
20  0   55      0
21  0   66      0
22  4   77      0
23  5   88      4
```

Then get the rows where `ID` is 0 and not equal to `prevID` - these are the first `0` rows:

```
> which(d$ID == 0 & d$prevID != 0)
[1]  6 12 18
```

Or use this to filter the original data.frame:

```
> d[which(d$ID == 0 & d$prevID != 0), ]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     ID  size prevID
  <int> <int>  <int>
1     0     2      5
2     0     4      5
3     0     3      5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea using `rleid` from `data.table`,

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)[, grp := rleid(ID == 0)][ID == 0, .(size = first(size)), by = grp]
```

which gives,

> ```
>    grp size
> 1:   2    2
> 2:   4    4
> 3:   6    3
> ```

In the `tidyverse`, one idea can be,

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 mutate(grp = cumsum(ID != 0)) %>% 
 filter(ID == 0) %>% 
 group_by(grp) %>% 
 summarise(size = first(size))
```

ehich gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>     grp   size
>   <int> <fctr>
> 1     5      2
> 2     7      4
> 3     9      3
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(row_idx = row_number()) %>%
  filter(ID==0) %>%
  filter(row_idx-lag(row_idx)>1 | row_number()==1) %>%
  select(-row_idx)
```

Output is:

```
1  0    2
2  0    4
3  0    3
```

```
#sample data
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 5L), size = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("2", "3", "4", "x"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"size"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -23L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a base R solution:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
ID    size
1      1
2      5
3      6
4      7
5      8
0      2
0      5
0      7
0      9
4      0
5      3
0      4
0      5
0      1
0      4
4      7
5      9
0      3
0      5
0      6
0      9
4      9
5      4", header = T)

ids <- which(df$ID == 0)

temp  <- c(TRUE, (diff(ids) != 1))

df$size[ids[temp]]
#[1] 2 4 3
```